# Class.forname redirection JAVA

Tags: java, class, classloader

i want to know if it's possible to redirect the object return by Class.forname. 
I explain if someone who use my program search with Class.forname test.nothere.found.class 
i want to redirect for this search to test.here.found.class because my problem is for cross-compatibility of my program package have change and i want to let older version of add-on compatible with new version of my program .

(add-on use the same classloader as me)

thanks

Comment: Can you supply your own classloader? If this is the case, then you can certainly override how class names are resolved, just look into the documentation for `ClassLoader`.

Comment: yes i can i will try it

Comment: Or just use a ServiceLoader. In the service name you can provide the needed class name.